# Android: Is "Allow Unknown Sources?" shown in all Android versions?

Tags: android

when trying to install a non-playstore .apk on Android Lolipop there is a prompt allowing you to go directly into the phone settings and check the box "allow unknown sources".

Is that true for all Android version?

Or do I need to go manually into settings and check this box there before being able to install third party apks?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're asking about. But the directly being able to control in the prompt is only available starting from Lollipop.